# AngularJS calculate total order amount

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to create a function that calculates price and quantity for all objects and returns a summary. My Code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.menu = {
        burgers: [
            {name: "Classic", price: 10, qty: 1},
            {name: "Mexican", price: 12, qty: 1}
        ],
        drinks: [
            {name: "Water", price: 5, qty: 1},
            {name: "Beer", price: 5, qty: 2}
        ]
    }
    $scope.calcTotal = function() {
        var total = 0;
        // return price*qty of all objects in both arrays 
        // inside menu object and sum them together
        return total;
    }
}
```

In template, I want to do something like this:

```
<div>{{ calcTotal() }}</div>
```

How should I write this `calcTotal()` function to make this happen?
In this case it should return 37.
Thanks in advance!
Also a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rnonpsLk/6/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not leverage the `reduce()` function?

This code will execute without errors **as long as `$scope.menu` contains only Arrays**

```
$scope.calcTotal = function() {
    var sum  = 0;
    for (var array in $scope.menu) {
        sum += $scope.menu[array].reduce(function(acc, el) { 
                   return acc + el.price * el.qty 
               }, 0);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Every Array in JavaScript implements the `map()` and `reduce()` primitives, these allow you to apply some code to every element in the array (in the case of `map`) or apply the same code to every element and pass it over to the next one so you can sum or accumulate values. (the argument named `acc` in `reduce`)

I recommend reading up on these (very useful) functions, they're the basis of functional programming languages, for the JS `reduce` you can check out the [MDN doc page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

As a last note, JavaScript's `for-in` iterates on every property **name** contained in `$scope.menu`, so `array` in this case will be names in your object like `'burgers'` and `'drinks'`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$scope.calcTotal = function() {
    var total = 0;
    for(i=0 ; i < $scope.menu.burgers.length ; i++){
        total += $scope.menu.burgers[i].price * $scope.menu.burgers[i].qty
    }

    for(i=0 ; i < $scope.menu.drinks.length ; i++){
        total += $scope.menu.drinks[i].price * $scope.menu.drinks[i].qty
    }
    // return price*qty of all items in both objects 
    // inside menu object and sum them together
    return total;
}
```

plunker - [updated Plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/rnonpsLk/9/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add logic as follows.

```
 $scope.calcTotal = function() {
        var total = 0;
        var burgers = $scope.menu.burgers;
        var drinks = $scope.menu.drinks;
        for (var i = 0 ; i < burgers.length; i++) {
            total += burgers[i].price * burgers[i].qty;
        }
        for (var i = 0 ; i < drinks.length; i++) {
            total += drinks[i].price * drinks[i].qty;
        }
        return total;
    }
```

Here is the updated plunker - http://jsfiddle.net/rnonpsLk/8/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) to loop the arrays, something like this:

```
$scope.calcTotal = function() {
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.menu, function(value, key) {
        angular.forEach(value, function(item, type) {
            total += item.price * item.qty;
        });
    });

    return total;
}
```

[Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnnbxady/).